# Only return rows when all are true

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In a slight mental tangle and I expect this is easier than I imagine. 
Got the following tables:

```
create table #x
(
handid int,
cardid int
)
insert into #x
values
(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),
(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,300),(2,400),(2,500),(2,8),
(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,300),(3,400),(3,7),(3,8),
(4,2),(4,300),(4,400),(4,500),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8)


create table #winners(cardid int)
insert into #winners values(300),(400),(500)

select a.* 
from 
        #x a 
        inner join #winners b
            on
            a.cardid = b.cardid
```

This returns the following:

[image]

I only want this query to return the rows when *all* of the three `cardid`s exists for a `handid`. So the desired result set would not include `handid` 3.

This is a model of reality.
In reality #x contains 500 mill records.

**EDIT**

Ok - there are actually *winners* that are made up of sets of data from `#winners` which have a variable number of records. So amending the original code to the following the result set should not include `handId` 1 or `handId` 3. I am also getting some unwanted duplicate records in the result set:

```
create table #x
(
handid int,
cardid int
)
insert into #x
values
(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8000),
(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,300),(2,400),(2,500),(2,8),
(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,300),(3,400),(3,7),(3,8),
(4,2),(4,300),(4,400),(4,500),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8)


create table #winners(winningComb char(1), cardid int)
insert into #winners values('A',300),('A',400),('A',500),('B',8000),('B',400)

select a.* 
from 
        #x a 
        inner join #winners b
            on
            a.cardid = b.cardid
```

Comment: Looks like the wrong table design. Probably a `handid, card1id, card2id, card3id` would be better suited for the requirement.

Comment: The name for this is relational division. For 500m records what indexes do you have? How many cardids on average per hand? How many different cardids in total in the table? How many will you generally be trying to match? Depending on the answers to this question you may be better off doing repeated joins than a group by.

Comment: looks like I'd better **EDIT** the OP!

Comment: @MartinSmith: 7 cardIds per hand. 52 different cardIds in the table. The `#winners` table will have 4m or 5m different `winningComb`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select handid
from #x  
where cardid in (select cardid from #winners)
group by handid
having count(handid) = (select count(distinct cardid)
                         from #winners);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6172)

Result:

```
| HANDID |
----------
|      2 |
|      4 |
```

Based on your edit, here is an attempt that returns the correct result however I am not sure if it will work with the larger dataset that you have:

```
;with cte as
(   
    select w1.cardid, w1.winningComb, w2.ComboCardCount
    from winners w1
    inner join
    (
        select COUNT(*) ComboCardCount, winningComb
        from winners
        group by winningComb
    ) w2
        on w1.winningComb = w2.winningComb
) 
select a.handid
from x a
inner join cte b
    on a.cardid = b.cardid
where a.cardid in (select cardid from cte)
group by handid, b.ComboCardCount
having COUNT(a.handid) = b.ComboCardCount
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e75f9/1)

Result:

```
| HANDID |
----------
|      2 |
|      4 |
```

Comment: +1 This produces the right answer without hardcoding the number of expected answers - its trivial to finish the question from here

Comment: apologies for changing the question after people have already worked on answers but I added the extra complexity into the OP

Comment: @whytheq how do you know what the winning combination is? Do they have to have all values in each set?

Comment: anything specified in `#winners` is a winning combination!! ... to be specific - 'winningComb A' might be a Royal flush in Diamonds, whereas 'winningComb B' might be a pair of Twos (diamond and spade); so how many ways are there to win at poker - lots!!

Comment: @whytheq - ***YOU*** need to add a score to each hand *(in whatever table `handid` refers to)*.  Then you can order by that score and pick the top 1.  There is a plethora of information online about how to assign a poker hand a ranking score.

Comment: @whytheq see my edit, I am not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for though

Comment: @bluefeet ....just out of interest: did you downvote the OP because I didn't mark a correct answer? (I always mark answers eventually)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
with cte as
(select a.* 
from 
        #x a 
        inner join #winners b
            on
            a.cardid = b.cardid ),
cte1 as 
     (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by handid order by cardid)  as row_num
       from cte),
cte2 as
     (select handid from cte1 where row_num=(select COUNT(*) from #winners) )
select * from cte where handid in (select handid from cte2)
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8ad5/7)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your query to

```
select a.*, count(a.*) as a_count 
from 
    #x a 
    inner join #winners b
        on
        a.cardid = b.cardid 
group by a.handid 
having a_count = 3
```

Comment: Why do you think that the number of cardids is always 3?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - my fault Tim as the OP before EDIT was not very clear

Answer (score 1):

@Bluefleets (+1) approach looks good in terms of performance for the data set; I guess with 500 million records the performance profile will change.

I think the OP wants the output in a slightly different format, something that a slight adaptation to @Bluefleet's code produces:

```
select * from #x where handid in (
select handid
from #x  
where cardid in (select cardid from #winners)
group by handid
having count(handid) = (select count(distinct cardid)
                         from #winners)
)
and cardid in (select cardid from #winners)
```

I would also consider the dread cursor solution - as it may perform better over a massive number of records depending on the data structure, indexes, number of winners and so on.

But without the full dataset I cant really say.